# how can i search for facebook users ,using facebook API(V3.3) in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, facebook-graph-api

I want to be able to search for any user using facebook API v3.3 in python 3.

I have written a function that can only return my details and that's fine, but now I want to search for any user and I am not succeeding so far, it seems as if in V3.3 I can only search for places and not users

1. The following function search and return a place, how can I modify it so that I can able to search for any Facebook users?

`def search_friend():
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
    find_user = graph.search(q='Durban  north beach',type='place')
    print(json.dumps(find_user, indent=4))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not search for users any more, that part of the search functionality has been removed a while ago.

Plus you would not be able to get any user info in the first place, unless the user in question logged in to your app first, and granted it permission to access at least their basic profile info.

Comment: I was trying to search users by their username, location, friend etc. So, is it impossible? When was the feature removed? Can I trust your answer? Please let me know links to related official announcements or notices.